# How to call static block with styles.css

Tags: css, magento, content-management-system

I am new to web designing and I added a static block to the header of my Magento website in `header.pthml` with

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('header_links')->toHtml()
?>
```

Now I am trying to positioning the block through css but this block is not in the regular `styles.css`.

How can I manage to get this block into the `styles.css` file to add position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add css use following code :

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addCss('css/mymodule/stylesheet.css');
```